# Not sure why `Justify-Between` keeping everything at the beginning of container

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am currently using tailwind css and am running in to an issue that my `justify-between` seems to be acting like `justify-start`. However when I use `justify-end` it brings everything to the end of the container.

Can someone kindly let me know what I'm missing and why my Logo and Navigation won't properly separate to different areas?

`Navbar.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
import Logo from "./Logo";
import headerLogo from "../../assets/images/headerImages/phreaquencyLogoDark.png";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className=" bg-off-white dark:bg-off-black">
      <div className="container w-full px-6 py-4 mx-auto md:flex md:justify-between md:items-center">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
          {/* Logo Div */}

          <a
            className="text-2xl font-bold text-gray-800 transition-colors duration-200 transform md:hidden dark:text-white lg:text-3xl hover:text-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300"
            href="#"
          >
            Phreaquency
          </a>
          <div className="hidden md:flex">
            <Logo
              logoSrc={headerLogo}
              logoAltSrc="phreaquency logo"
              logoLayout="intrinsic"
              logoObjectFit="contain"
              logoWidth="150px"
              logoHeight="40px"
              className="relative z-10 flex items-center w-auto"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex md:hidden">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-600 dark:hover:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600 dark:focus:text-gray-400"
              aria-label="toggle menu"
            >
              <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" className="w-6 h-6 fill-current">
                <path
                  fillRule="evenodd"
                  d="M4 5h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>

          {/* Navigation Div */}
          <div className="items-center md:flex">
            <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:mx-6">
              <a
                className="my-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 transition-colors duration-200 transform dark:text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-blue-400 md:mx-4 md:my-0"
                href="#"
              >
                Home
              </a>
              <a
                className="my-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 transition-colors duration-200 transform dark:text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-blue-400 md:mx-4 md:my-0"
                href="#"
              >
                Shop
              </a>
              <a
                className="my-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 transition-colors duration-200 transform dark:text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-blue-400 md:mx-4 md:my-0"
                href="#"
              >
                Contact
              </a>
              <a
                className="my-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 transition-colors duration-200 transform dark:text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-blue-400 md:mx-4 md:my-0"
                href="#"
              >
                About
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

[image: When I inspect on the navbar]

Comment: Which of this is the problematic div ```<div className="container w-full px-6 py-4 mx-auto md:flex md:justify-between md:items-center">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between">```. You have to divs with justify between and it's hard to determine which is the one giving the problem you've described. Maybe provide a codesandbox example

Comment: Heya Joshua - thanks for the response and sorry I wasn't more specific in my original question. To answer your question it is the `<div className="container w-full px-6 py-4 mx-auto md:flex md:justify-between md:items-center"> ` that seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: That div has only one direct child, so I don't think there's a problem there, I think you need to adjust your css on the other div that's a child of that, the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a separator `div` with `flex-1` between the two `div`s:

```
import React from 'react';
import Logo from './Logo';
import headerLogo from '../../assets/images/headerImages/phreaquencyLogoDark.png';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className=' bg-off-white dark:bg-off-black'>
      <div className='container w-full px-6 py-4 mx-auto md:flex md:justify-between md:items-center'>
        <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
          {/* Logo Div */}

          <a
            className='text-2xl font-bold text-gray-800 transition-colors duration-200 transform md:hidden dark:text-white lg:text-3xl hover:text-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300'
            href='#'
          >
            Phreaquency
          </a>
          <div className='hidden md:flex'>
            <Logo
              logoSrc={headerLogo}
              logoAltSrc='phreaquency logo'
              logoLayout='intrinsic'
              logoObjectFit='contain'
              logoWidth='150px'
              logoHeight='40px'
              className='relative z-10 flex items-center w-auto'
            />
          </div>
          <div className='flex md:hidden'>
            <button
              type='button'
              className='text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-600 dark:hover:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600 dark:focus:text-gray-400'
              aria-label='toggle menu'
            >
              <svg viewBox='0 0 24 24' className='w-6 h-6 fill-current'>
                <path
                  fillRule='evenodd'
                  d='M4 5h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2z'
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>

          {/* Separator div */}
          <div className='flex-1'></div>

          {/* Navigation Div */}
          <div className='items-center md:flex'>
            <div className='flex flex-col md:flex-row md:mx-6'>
              <a
                className='my-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 transition-colors duration-200 transform dark:text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-blue-400 md:mx-4 md:my-0'
                href='#'
              >
                Home
              </a>
              <a
                className='my-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 transition-colors duration-200 transform dark:text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-blue-400 md:mx-4 md:my-0'
                href='#'
              >
                Shop
              </a>
              <a
                className='my-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 transition-colors duration-200 transform dark:text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-blue-400 md:mx-4 md:my-0'
                href='#'
              >
                Contact
              </a>
              <a
                className='my-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 transition-colors duration-200 transform dark:text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-blue-400 md:mx-4 md:my-0'
                href='#'
              >
                About
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```